# serve when is receive_buf called

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

Hello I wanted to know when is the receive_buf vom a serve called. Because for me it looks like it get called on a time out. But I did not find anything in the documentation. I also looked at the source code but I found nothing.
[serdev.h](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/linux/blob/master/include/linux/serdev.h)

Comment: See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/serdev/serdev-ttyport.c#L35

Comment: I found it but I do not know what triggers the call.